# How can I display category in http bar?

Tags: django

Working on E-Commerce shop. I have created catogories function which displays the items with particular category.

Everything works fine, but I would like also to display the category name after `/category/`.

I tried GET method but I get an error. Do you have any adivse? Value in the button is the Category.

**Form in Templates:**

```
<form method='post' action='/category/' class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="nav-link purple darken-4" type="submit" name="S" value="S" style="background-color: grey;">Shirts</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="nav-link purple darken-4" type="submit" name="S" value="O" style="background-color: grey;">Outwear</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="nav-link purple darken-4" type="submit" name="S" value="SW" style="background-color: grey;">Sportwear</button>
    </li>
</form>
```

**Views:**

```
def category(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.POST.get('S', False):
            s = request.POST['S']
            objects_display = Item.objects.filter(category=s)

            if objects_display.exists():
                context ={
                    "objects": objects_display
                }

                return render(request, "shop/categories.html", context)
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'no items found')
                return redirect('item-list')
```

**URLs:**

```
path('category/', category, name='category'),
```

Comment: Are you using a form for a nav bar? Why not just use `<a href=...` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic URL you can do easy, pass category_name parameter in URL and access in view and do query base on parameter value if the parameter is none you can provide all item or you can give a message as empty

url

```
path('category/', category, name='category'),
re_path('category/(?P<category_name>[0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)', category, name='category'),
```

views

```
def category(request, category_name=None):
    if category_name:
        objects_display = Item.objects.filter(category=category_name) 
    else:
        objects_display = Item.objects.all()

    context ={
        "objects": objects_display
    }

    return render(request, "shop/categories.html", context)
```

Category also you can do dynamic you can create a category model and add forainkey in an item in view every time you can pass all category object in context and write for loop on category object and inside loop you can write HTML li tag so it will be going fully dynamic

HTML

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link purple darken-4" href="{% url 'category' category_name='category name' %} style="background-color: grey;">Shirts</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: I did everything as above and Page not found (404. Not sure what is wrong ? :(

Comment: are you sure HTML page is there and in URLs you need to import re_path

Comment: Ahh forgot about re_path import. All works fine now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'a' instead of form
Template

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link purple darken-4" href="{% url 'category' category_name='s' %} style="background-color: grey;">Shirts</a>
 </li> (and others)
```

url

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>\w+)/$', views.category, name="category"),
```

views

```
def category(request, category_name):
    objects_display = Item.objects.filter(category=category_name)

    if objects_display.exists():
        context ={
            "objects": objects_display
        }

        return render(request, "shop/categories.html", context)
    else:
         messages.warning(request, 'no items found')
         return redirect('item-list')
```